# Liouville's Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Why does $f(z)=\cos(z^2)$ not contradict Liouville's theorem?

Is the best approach to put $\cos(z^2)$ into its Taylor expansion?

How can I visualize $\cos(z^2)$?

Comment: Just pick a trajectory which gives cosh, which happens along the imaginary line for cos.

Comment: See the question that is posed at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics.

Answer (score 14):

Because in $\mathbb{C}$, $\cos$ and $\sin$ are not bounded functions like they are in $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, $\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$, so $\cos$ grows exponentially on the imaginary axis.

Comment: Well, they are nice, they just aren't bounded (indeed, the content of Liouville's theorem is that if a function is nice enough and is not completely boring, then it must be unbounded).

Comment: @WillR They are nice in the sense of regularity, but their unboundedness makes them "not nice" for certain uses (e.g. in contour integration).

Comment: @WillR: agree, the constants have all the nice properties we need and yet are boring enough. :)